# Append $index to the end of the string in Smarty3

Tags: php, smarty, smarty3

I have the following HTML code:

```
<input type="text"
       name="line_item[hotel_info][{{$index}}][second_last_name_{{$index}}]"
       value="{{$PREVIOUS_REQUEST.hotel_info.$index.second_last_name_$index}}"
>
```

What's the right way to append `$index` to the string being passed to the value? This `$PREVIOUS_REQUEST.hotel_info.$index.second_last_name_$index` is failing since Smarty doesn't like the `_$index` at the end of the string. Any help?

**UPDATE:** using `cat`:

I have tried using `cat` modifiers but still not working:

```
{{$PREVIOUS_REQUEST.hotel_info.$index.hotel_name_|cat:$index}}
```

Return `0` which is the value of `$index` but I need the value stored in the var.

Comment: `{{$PREVIOUS_REQUEST.hotel_info.$index.second_last_name_{$index}}}` maybe, as it looks like a [variable variable](http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.syntax.variables.tpl).

Comment: @bishop does not work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you will need to use an intermediate variable:

```
{assign "sln" "second_last_name_$index"}
value="{{$PREVIOUS_REQUEST.hotel_info.$index.$sln}}"
```

Example:

```
$PREVIOUS_REQUEST = [ 'hotel_info' => [
    0 => [ 'second_last_name_0' => 'foo' ],
    1 => [ 'second_last_name_1' => 'bar' ],
]];

$smarty = new \Smarty;
$smarty->assign('PREVIOUS_REQUEST', $PREVIOUS_REQUEST);
$smarty->assign('index', 0);
$smarty->display(<<<'EOTPL'
string:
{assign "sln" "second_last_name_$index"}
index="{{$index}}"
index="{{$sln}}"
value="{{$PREVIOUS_REQUEST.hotel_info.$index.$sln}}"

EOTPL
);
```

Outputs:

```
index="0"
index="second_last_name_0"
value="foo"
```

Comment: How do you get that debug information? Using `{{debug}}` in the template?

Comment: Yeah, they're just variables, so I just use Smarty's variable expansion `{{$some_variable_in_scope}}`.

Comment: I am not getting the same output as you :-( I have added `{{debug}}` to the template but I don't see any information

Comment: The literal "{{debug}}" doesn't mean anything. In the example above, the template is a string (rather than a file). In that string template, I have additional smarty calls that output the different variables, like `index="{{$index}}"` tells Smarty to replace "{{$index}}" with whatever value "$index" has at that point in time.